# Como indicar que uma variável é um objeto do Express utilizando JavaScript Docs?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ide

Estou utilizando o consign para fazer a inclusão automática de rotas em uma aplicação construída com Express. Em determinado arquivo tenho a rota:

```
module.exports = app => {
    app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
        //...
    })
}
```

Mas essa abordagem, ao menos para mim, resultou na perda do autocomplete do IntelliSense do JavaScript no VS Code.

Seria possível utilizando as marcações de documentação do JavaScript instruir a IDE/Editor, neste caso VS Code a entender que **app** é um objeto do Express, levando o mesmo a "reativar" o IntelliSense? Como isso poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível, se você criar uma anotação com o tipo dessa variável.

O IntelliSense aceita anotações JSDoc para indicar o tipo da variável com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
/** 
 * @param { string } arg1
 * @param { boolean } arg2
 */
function minhaFuncao(arg1, arg2) {

}
```

A partir desse modelo, você pode verificar no módulo `index.d.ts` do Express, que o tipo do seu `app`, é `Express`, logo você pode criar uma indicação para o tipo do seu `app` com:

```
/** @param { import('express').Express } app */
module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    // ...
  })
}
```

A partir daí, o IntelliSense sabe o tipo do `app`, e logo também reconhece a assinatura do método `post`, reconhecendo também o tipo dos argumentos `req`, `res` e `next`.